# NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/exception/ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss

We are migrating to Wildfly 10 from WebSphere and using the newer Hibernate 5 jars or, I should say, attempting to use them.  Upon deployment of an ear, we are getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'xxxEndPoint' defined in class path resource 
[config/context-ep-xxx.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/hibernate/exception/ConstraintViolationException
```

It almost appears as though the hibernate jar file hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar is not part of the classpath even though it's required.  We even created an explicit deploy in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to no avail.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
   <exclusions>
       <module name="org.slf4j" />
       <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
       <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
       <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
       <module name="org.javassist" />
   </exclusions>
   <dependencies>
       <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
   </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also, we are *not* using maven.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the ear file (you can change it to a .zip if necessary or use 7zip).  Double check that the expected hibernate jars are included in the ear you are trying to deploy.  If not, try adding it to the ear along with updating the manifest.

Comment: The expected Hibernate files are already included in Wildfly under the modules directory.  Why are they not loaded by the app server?